# How to avoid asyncronous operations from setting state on an unmounted component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, synchronization

Let's imagine a component loading data from the server using *fetch*.

```
fetch(`${url}`).then(response => {
                    this.setState({
                        ...
                    })
                })
```

But it is possible that data is loaded **after** the component is unmounted which will lead to an attempt to *setState* on an unmounted component.

How severe is such an issue and how to avoid it from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to take a look at the [`AbortController` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort). As using [`_mounted` is considered](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) an anti-pattern :

```
class Test extends React.ComponentComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.controller = new AbortController();

        fetch(`${url}`, { signal: controller.signal }).then(response => {
            this.setState({ })
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.controller.abort()
    }
}
```

Calling the `abort` fucntion of your controller will cancel your `fetch`. I would recommend calling it in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle function.

Browser compatibility : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort#Browser_compatibility

Comment: as you pinted in your comment, i saw the same blogpost , and the part that gave me the same idea for not using ismounted() `An easy migration strategy for anyone upgrading their code to avoid isMounted() is to track the mounted status yourself. Just set a _isMounted property to true in componentDidMount and set it to false in componentWillUnmount, and use this variable to check your component’s status.`  , the post is to avoid ismounted() . not this._mounted -.-

Answer (score 0):

It's a no-op since it does nothing, but if the state is somewhat "big" or resource heavy, then it may lead to little memory leaks

I've encountered this using drawernavigator of react navigation v2 module, i did a dirty workaround by having a variable that tells me if the component is mounted or unmounted

```
class Modal extends React.PureComponent {
....
_mounted=false;
componentDidMount(){this._mounted = true}
componentWillUnmount(){this._mounted = false}
....
```

and then everytime i call setstate i check if this._mounted is true before doing it.

Now in react navigation v3 the drawer doesn't unmount the screens so i'm happy without using it